# What is wrong with the proof of this incorrect formula for the probability of $A\cap B$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

The probability that events $A$ or $B$ (or possibly both at once) will occur is $P(A\cup B)$. Since we can think of $A\cup B$ as the set-theoretic analog of inclusive logical disjunction $\vee$, I thought that we could look at $P(A\cap B)$ (i.e. the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur at once) as the set-theoretic analog of logical conjunction $\wedge$. From De Morgan's laws we know that $p\wedge q$ is equivalent to $\neg\left (  \neg p \vee \neg q\right )$. Applying this to our sets $A$ and $B$ and recognizing that the complement $A^c=\Omega \setminus A$ (where $\Omega$ is the sample space) is the set-theoretic analog of logical negation $\neg$, we get:

$$P(A\cap B)=P((A^c\cup B^c)^c)$$

We know that for any event $E$ it is true that $P(E^c)=1-P(E^c)$. Using this we get:

$$P((A^c\cup B^c)^c)=1-P(A^c\cup B^c)$$

Using the [third probability axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) we get:

$$1-P(A^c\cup B^c)=1-(P(A^c)+P(B^c))$$

Applying the $P(E^c)=1-P(E^c)$ again yields:

$$1-(P(A^c)+P(B^c))=1-((1-P(A))+(1-P(B)))$$

Simplifying we finally get:

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-1$$

Which is clearly nonsense. What's going on here?

Comment: The part just after "Using the third probability axiom" is wrong.

Comment: In order to apply the third probability axiom, A and B must be disjoint sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third axiom only applies if $A^c$ and $B^c$ are disjoint. But that means that $A$ and $B$ cover the whole space, in which case the sum of their probabilities is $\geq1$, and the final calculation makes complete sense.

(In general this is very close to the basic inclusion-exclusion principle.)

Comment: Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ be the set of elementary outcomes, and let $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{3, 4, 5\}$.  Then $A^c = \{4, 5\}$ and $B^c \{1, 2\}$ which are disjoint but $A$ and $B$ are not complementary in $S$:  their intersection contains $\{3\}$.  Requiring $A^c \cap B^c = \varnothing$ does not mean $A$ and $B$ are complementary.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The part just after "Using the third probability axiom" is wrong. The events $A^c$ and $B^c$ are not necessarily disjoint.

**Remark:** Manipulations can easily go awry. If one draws a generic Venn diagram, and checks each new assertion against the picture, slips become much less likely.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Is there a way to proceed with the proof and conclude $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$?

Comment: @user132181 No, because the statement $$\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A] \Pr[B]$$ requires *independence* of events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: In general it is not true that $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$. Just draw a Venn diagram with $A$ and $B$ disjoint. There are many more complicated examples. The equation you are asking about holds precisely if $A$ and $B$ are **independent**.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said, you can only use the third probability axiom if A and B are disjoint. I would just note that if you do assume this, then the conclusion you have made is not nonsense and you actually have shown that the probability of the empty set is 0. Good Job! :)